# Firebase Security Rules: Is checking database value equally secure with checking auth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I was wondering if checking a 'database value' (example below) for a user is equally, more, or less secure than 'checking auth' (example below).

Could checking the 'database value' be secure enough for an app?

checking database value:

```js
"root.child('account').child($uid).child('role').val() === 'admin'"
```

checking auth:

```js
"auth != null"
```

Answer (score 1):

If only you or any authorized user can edit that role in database, then yes it's safe to do using security rules. I'd recommend storing a separate `admins` node in database and check for user UID in that node so it's easier to write security rules to secure that.

```
admins
  |-user1: true
  |-user2: true
```

Then you can write the following rule to check if user is an admin:

```
root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() === true
```

As mentioned earlier, make sure only authorized users can add new admins to this node.

However, do note that data in realtime database can be access in security rules of realtime database only. If you need to use Firestore or Storage anyday later, you won't be able to check for admin in their security rules. In such cases, using [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) might be a better way.

---

If you need to check if the user requesting the data is an admin, you should be using `auth.uid` instead of `$uid`. `$uid` is a wildcard and will take up matching value in the path being accessed. Using the `$uid` itself doesn't sounds that secure as if I try making request to `/path/($uid=someId)`, your rules will be checking for that `someId` in admin node so users can try passing multiple IDs which isn't secure.